# "Hello World" Failure Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: c, gcc

I get a failure

```
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

to search the roots of the problem i did try it even with the Hello World code

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        printf("Hello World\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Compiled with

```
sudo gcc Zeiger.h -o Zeiger,                        
sudo chmod +x Zeiger
```

And run with

```
sudo ./Zeiger
```

Then the Failure I get is:

```
./Zeiger: 1: ./Zeiger: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: `gcc Zeiger.h`....what the `h`?

Comment: That's C, don't use the C++ tag.

Comment: Why the `sudo`??

Comment: Does `mv Zeiger.h Zeiger.c` and then, `sudo gcc Zeiger.c -o Zeiger` help? (I'm not sure of the `sudo` part , though).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass the header file to gcc

It's just `sudo gcc -o Zeiger Zeiger.c`

Comment: Sorry, but are you asking or answering? For the former, use the comments.

Comment: OK, so please form an actual answer out of the subject matter. Also, please work towards getting a bit more rep which helps you to comment anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You mean :

```
gcc Zeiger.c -o Zeiger
```

instead of :

```
gcc Zeiger.h -o Zeiger
```

Answer (score 1):

`gcc Zeiger.c -o Zeiger`

and finished.
Thank you very much!

Comment: bot armo and Marievi answered your question before you gave the same answer yourself. Out of curtesy you should consider accepting and upvoting one of their answers